# Failed to execute 'open' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Invalid URL in Angular using Apollo client

Tags: javascript, angular, types, graphql, hasura

I am using Hasura GraphQL cloud service to query some data.
Running an Angular app on localhost, from here I try to connect to an already created project which has some tables.
I got the hasura url and when I try to establish connection but getting an error in console: `ERROR ApolloError: SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'open' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Invalid URL`

What I have tried so far :

- Under hasura project, the environment variables cors is set to *
- Using codegen I was able to generate schema for the table I was querying into
- Could not see a network call being made
- Have imported the module where the connection is being made to appmodule
- Added the necessary packages.

Code which I have tried so far :

graphql.module.ts (comes under app)

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ApolloModule, APOLLO_OPTIONS } from 'apollo-angular';
import { ApolloClientOptions, InMemoryCache } from '@apollo/client/core';
import { HttpLink } from 'apollo-angular/http';

export const uri = 'http://***/v1/graphql';
export function createApollo(httpLink: HttpLink): ApolloClientOptions<any> {
    return {
        link: httpLink.create({ uri }),
        cache: new InMemoryCache(),
    };
}

@NgModule({
    exports: [ApolloModule],
    providers: [
        {
            provide: APOLLO_OPTIONS,
            useFactory: createApollo,
            deps: [HttpLink],
        },
    ],
})
export class GraphQLModule {}
```

The below one is my generated code using codegen, and I am using this to do an api call from app component :

```
import { gql } from 'apollo-angular';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as Apollo from 'apollo-angular';
export type GetRoleQueryVariables = { [key: string]: never };

export type GetRoleQuery = {
    __typename?: 'query_root';
    role: Array<{
        __typename?: 'role';
        created_at?: any | null;
        created_by?: any | null;
        deleted_at?: any | null;
        deleted_by?: any | null;
        id: any;
        name: string;
    }>;
};

export const GetRoleDocument = gql`
    query getRole {
        role {
            created_at
            created_by
            deleted_at
            deleted_by
            id
            name
        }
    }
`;

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class GetRoleGQL extends Apollo.Query<GetRoleQuery, GetRoleQueryVariables> {
    override document = GetRoleDocument;

    constructor(apollo: Apollo.Apollo) {
        super(apollo);
    }
}
```

Api call :

```
this._getRoles.watch().valueChanges.subscribe((res: any) => {})
```

This is where the error occurs, and the console produces the above mentioned error.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you

What I have tried so far :

- Under hasura project, the environment variables cors is set to *
- Using codegen I was able to generate schema for the table I was querying into
- Could not see a network call being made
- Have imported the module where the connection is being made to appmodule
- Added the necessary packages.

Expecting to do a successful api call and get the table data